# index of при переходе по домену сайта

Tags: php, веб-программирование, cms, opencart, index

Привет все доброжелателям и не очень!

С вебом и сайто-строением, дел почти не имел. Но нужно было собрать сайтик на opencart. После муторных споров с хостером и привязкой домена я попал наконец-то в свою админку. Накатил CMS. Перехожу по домену. что бы глянуть. 
В общем суть проблемы: На скриншоте, нужно что бы открывался сам сайт. А не эта директория, гуглил.. Но толку особо нет, у меня нет файлов которые там упоминаются.

Не минусуйте просто так, я с этим не сталкивался.

[image: Сама проблема - скриншот]

Comment: Можешь показать вложенность каталогов на хостинге? Чую у тебя лишняя папка, убедись что скопировал код в нужный каталог

Comment: До этого ставил opencart через встроенные скрипты, вроде все открывалось. Удалил и поставил вручную, вроде установил все. Сейчас я удалил вообще полностью все что ставил. Так что показать нечего. Но проблема осталась даже после удаления всех лишних файлов и папок.

Comment: Суть не в этом, нужно код опенкарта кинуть в корень, а что у вас за каталог ocStore?

Comment: public_html - он ведь и является корнем? Скрипт установки поставил opencart именно в этот каталог. Я менял права доступа файлам index.php на 7 5 5. 
Каталог ocStore - это русифицированный opencart. По сути я сделал тоже самое что и установщик скриптов.
p.s. cPanel (php)

Comment: Что вообще означает index of/ ? Я так понимаю это каталог, сервер не видит главного index-а и выдает каталог сам. Или что? :)

Comment: Ну типа того, ещё проблема может быть в настройках .htaccess, но тут я вам не помогу

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Спасибо, **Анатолию** что пытался помочь!

Все оказалось намного проще. На случай если кто, столкнется отвечаю. Все файлы которые идут с опенкартом, нужно полностью распаковать (т.е. вытащить из папки, которая идет с установщиком). 
И ещё присвойте **права доступа 755 всем idex-сам.php**
Вот скриншот, как примерно нужно всё расположить именно в корне хоста. Т.е. public_html у меня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]